# Unresolved External errors linking to SFML (SFML 2.2, Visual Studio Community 2013)

Tags: c++, dll, linker, sfml, unresolved-external

Attempting to link a new C++ project with SFML, I did the following:

- Created an empty project.
- C/C++ >> General: Additional Include Directories: added SFML include directory and inheriting from project defaults.
- Linker >> Additional Library Directories: added SFML lib directory and inheriting from project defaults.
- Added additional dependencies: winmm.lib, openal32.lib, sndfile.lib, opengl32.lib, gdi32.lib, glew.lib, freetype.lib, jpeg.lib, sfml-system-s-d.lib, sfml-audio-s-d.lib, sfml-window-s-d.lib, sfml-graphics-s-d.lib, plus inheriting from project defaults.
- All other project settings are default.

I copied the sample main() from http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php .

When I attempt to build the program, I get 15 LNK2019 Unresolved External errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (__imp_??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::close(void)" (__imp_?close@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::isOpen(void)const " (__imp_?isOpen@Window@sf@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::pollEvent(class sf::Event &)" (__imp_?pollEvent@Window@sf@@QAE_NAAVEvent@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::display(void)" (__imp_?display@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Color::Color(unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (__imp_??0Color@sf@@QAE@EEEE@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::clear(class sf::Color const &)" (__imp_?clear@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::draw(class sf::Drawable const &,class sf::RenderStates const &)" (__imp_?draw@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVDrawable@2@ABVRenderStates@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (__imp_??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (__imp_??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Shape::setFillColor(class sf::Color const &)" (__imp_?setFillColor@Shape@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0CircleShape@sf@@QAE@MI@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape(void)" (__imp_??1CircleShape@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

2 LNK2001 Unresolved Externals:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::Green" (__imp_?Green@Color@sf@@2V12@B)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (__imp_?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B)
```

and an LNK1120:

```
1>C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\DLLTest\Debug\DLLTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
```

No program is built.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, and it's more likely to be about linking to DLLs than about SFML. What am I doing wrong?

**Resolution:** This was SFML-specific: I was linking to the static versions of the SFML DLLs (the ones with -s in the name). I switched to the dynamic versions (sfml-system-d.lib, for example), and the project built, although to run it I'll need to have the SFML DLLs in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Please include the error messages in your question.

Comment: Added the error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are linking the Static-Debug Version of the SFML-Libs. Do you really want to build a static version? If so you have to define SFML_STATIC. Otherwise remove the -s option in the Library-names.

Comment: This did it -- looks like the problem was with the SFML library names I was using. I _thought_ it was something obvious... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The dllspec(dllimport) I believe means that you are attempting to dynamically link.  SFML_STATIC needs to be defined, or put the dlls in your working directory and change names in additional libraries.

Comment: Thank you! If I could accept your answer as well, I would.